# Npm soap package - editing SOAP header

Tags: xml, node.js, soap, meteor

I'm using this package to establish api connection with some server. The API is built using SOAP and XML technologies. To establish connection in my meteor.js application I'm using this package

https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap

This is how my code looks like:

```
global.initSoapDexConnection = function() {
    Soap.createClient(
        Meteor.absoluteUrl('dss/DEXSingle.wsdl'),
        {
            endpoint: Meteor.settings.SOAP.DSS,
            forceSoap12Headers: true
        },
        function(err, client) {
            deleteFilesFromFolder(Meteor.settings.ApiInvestigator.path, true, ['DEX_procedures.txt','xml_newest.xml']);

            var security = new Soap.WSSecurity(
                'SOME LOGIN',
                'SOME PASSWORD',
                {
                    passwordType: 'PasswordText',
                    hasTimeStamp: true
                }
            );

            client.setSecurity(security);

            client.addListener('request', function(request) {
                console.log(request.constructor === String);
                initReportCreation(PrettyData.pd.xml(request), '.xml', 'listener_request');
            });

            client.Ping({}, function() {
                var responseForFile = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                    responseForFile += '<<<<<PARAMETER ' + i + '>>>>>\n\n';
                    responseForFile += JSON.stringify(arguments[i], null, 5);
                    responseForFile += '\n\n';
                }

                if (Meteor.settings.ApiInvestigator && Meteor.settings.ApiInvestigator.path) {
                    initReportCreation(responseForFile);
                } else {
                    console.log(responseForFile);
                }
            });

        }
    );
};
```

The question is, how can I edit security XML before request is made? Say I want to add new attribute to Password or Username XML tags.